# SharePoint 2010 Beta 2 with SQL 2008 R2

Tags: deployment, installation, sql-server, beta

Are there instructions for installing SharePoint 2010 Beta 2 with SQL 2008 R2? I notice that none of the installation resources thus far describe using R2.

(At the time of writing R2 is at November CTP and contains Geneva components.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed successfully on SQL R2.
Not hotfixes etc needed it just worked, but make sure you have the up to date CTP.

Answer (score 0):

FYI...Chris Quick over at EndUserSharePoint.com is doing a [live blogging session](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/11/17/real-world-sharepoint-2010-installation-by-chris-quick/?utm%5Fsource=feedburner&utm%5Fmedium=feed&utm%5Fcampaign=Feed%3A+EndUserSharepoint+%28End+User+SharePoint%29) this morning installing SharePoint 2010 beta.  He might be using SQL 2008 R2 for the database.

Comment: Here's a link from the Microsoft SharePoint Team on update installs when using Server 2008 R2
http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/11/19/installation-notice-for-the-sharepoint-server-public-beta-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008-r2-and-microsoft-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Andreas Glaser has written a full multi-part walkthrough [on his blog here](http://andreasglaser.net/post/2009/11/17/Installing-SharePoint-Server-2010-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2-and-SQL-Server-2008-R2-Part-1-Overview.aspx). Thanks Andreas!!